# Restore power button to default behaviour

Tags: buttons

I have LG G2 (D801) on Android 5.0.2 Lollipop, rooted. The power button stopped working. I am pretty sure an app messed up its behavior - I don't know which one of the many I recently un/installed trying to fix another issue. I am pretty sure it's not a hardware issue.

How could I restore its default behavior: press to optionally lock the screen and long press to bring up the power menu?

Comment: Not very helpful if you ask me. How do we even suspect what may be interfering with your power button if you don't even list those apps that you've tried and are still installed? Simply backup all of them and remove each of them. Restart and see whether the button functions normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go full stock with a factory flash. See if the problem is present then. If it is, it is a hardware issue, and you can claim warranty. If it works, be a lot more careful with your apps next time.

Comment: I thought of doing the same but figured I would post the question in case someone has a quicker/less brute force approach. If no one else comes up with that kind of answer, I will accept yours. Thanks